# Verifying download box pop up using selenium

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, webdriver

I have a website where I am using selenium for integration testing.

I have link there that is generated using multiple variables from page.
I would like to verify the download pop up box is displaying if at all possible, when i am simulating click on link to download the file.

I know i can have JsUnit that will do that for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thnx to Slanec i have took up your examples.

Ok after investigation I have decided that best solution will be
something along this line.

```
    public int GetFileLenghtFromUrlLocation(string location)
    {
        int len = 0;
        int timeoutInSeconds = 5;

        // paranoid check for null value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(location)) return 0;

        // Create a web request to the URL
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(location);
        myRequest.Timeout = timeoutInSeconds * 1000;
        myRequest.AddRange(1024);
        try
        {
            // Get the web response
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            // Make sure the response is valid
            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == myResponse.StatusCode)
            {
                // Open the response stream
                using (Stream myResponseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (myResponseStream == null) return 0;

                    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(myResponseStream))
                    {
                        len = rdr.ReadToEnd().Length;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error saving file from URL:" + err.Message, err);
        }

        return len;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is lousy when working with downloads. Clicking the link will get you into trouble.

You could, however, make a request [using HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) (or maybe just a file get through [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)) for the link specified and assert a `200 OK` response. Or try to get the file - [this is my favourite tool](https://github.com/Ardesco/Ebselen/blob/master/ebselen-core/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/ebselen/customhandlers/FileDownloader.java) for this with Selenium.

Comment: do you know about similar in C# (i suppose i could write something similar but still)

Comment: Oh, sorry, you didn't specify a language. I don't know C# at all, but there has to be lots of C# HttpRequest libraries (and related SO questions). Good luck!